# Magento 2: Customer group price quantity

Tags: magento2

When I add a different price for a customer group, I need to insert the quantity, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tier pricing lets you offer a quantity discount from a product listing or product page in the storefront. The discount can be applied to a specific store view or customer group.

In the Qty field, enter the quantity that must be ordered to receive the discount for the selected customer group.

You can read more details on the below Magento official guide.

> https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html

Hope it helps!!!